# association confusion when used with mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an "Factory module" which has "has_many" relationship with "Icecream Model". I have done mixin of factory module with another "Owner model" so that i can have a relationship of "owner" with "icecreams table". Problem is I am not able to fetch icecreams with the "owner" object i think something is wrong with the relationship definition.
The definition from Factory model is below.

```
module Factory
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do    
    has_many :icecreams, :dependent => :nullify 
  end
```

The relationship definition from Icecream is like this

```
Class Icecream < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :factory, :class_name => "Owner", :foreign_key => "factory_id"
```

Comment: The moral to the story here is to write a test for it, make it work without fancy mixins first, then move the code to a mixin and make sure the test still passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
The association must be defined both sides(has_many, belongs_to).
I had defined the foreign_key: "factory_id" on the belongs_to side.
Now from the has_many side i wanted my association to use look_up with "factory_id", therefore i have to make the foreign_key: "factory_id" on the has_many side as well.

```
module Factory
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do    
    has_many :icecreams, :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => "factory_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i hope it will use for you.

> ```
> module Factory   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
>   def self.included(base)> 
>      base.instance_eval("has_many :icecreams, :dependent => :nullify )   
>   end
> ```

Comment: ActiveSupport::Concern is there so that you don't have to write with the `included` hook. ;)